# How to use Sidekiq

Tags: sidekiq

I'm trying to use [Sidekiq](https://rubygems.org/gems/sidekiq) to send emails.

I've installed Sidekiq as per the wiki. Then in my controller:

`UserMailer.delay_for(2.minutes).send_invoice(@invoice.id, set_db)`

In the sidekiq dashboard I can see the job scheduled and I can move it to enqueued but then nothing happens.

The problem is not with the mail itself as if I try:

`UserMailer.send_invoice(@invoice.id, set_db).deliver`

does work and the email is delivered perfectly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't start a sidekiq worker:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```